# Is it possible to swap two tokens with macros in C++

Tags: c++, macros, preprocessor-directive

Consider this C++ program:

```
#include <cstdio>

#define FOO BAR
#define BAR FOO

#define QUOTE(X) #X
#define EXPAND(X) QUOTE(X)

int main()
{
    printf("%s expands to %s\n", QUOTE(FOO), EXPAND(FOO));
    printf("%s expands to %s\n", QUOTE(BAR), EXPAND(BAR));
}
```

It outputs:

```
FOO expands to FOO
BAR expands to BAR
```

This is because `FOO` expands to `BAR` which expands to `FOO` which is not expanded again. And similarly for the second line.

**Question:** Is it possible to swap `FOO` and `BAR` with macros? I.e., is it possible to replace the two lines:

```
#define FOO BAR
#define BAR FOO
```

with something else so that the program will output:

```
FOO expands to BAR
BAR expands to FOO
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not quite understand why you want to do this, or why you use macros in the first place. Hence, this may not fit your needs exactly:

```
#include <cstdio>

#define QUOTE(X) #X
#define REPLACE_FOO QUOTE(BAR)
#define REPLACE_BAR QUOTE(FOO)
#define EXPAND(X) REPLACE_##X

int main()
{
    printf("%s expands to %s\n", QUOTE(FOO), EXPAND(FOO));
    printf("%s expands to %s\n", QUOTE(BAR), EXPAND(BAR));
}
```

I am rather certain that there is a solution to your actual problem that does not rely on macros.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this was not quite what I was looking for. I don't want to change the `QUOTE` and `EXPAND` macros. They are just there to be able to print out how `FOO` and `BAR` are expanded.

Comment: @DavidBrink if you cannot change `QUOTE` nor `EXPAND` you should mention that in the quesiton. Though, I don't see how this can be done without modifiying at least one of them.